# How to navigate to the same route with different param with React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to figure out how I can navigate to the same route but changing the param only.

For example, here are the routes declared within my `BrowserRouter`:

```
/financial/:productId/checklist
/financial/:productId/taxes
/financial/:productId/accounting
/operation/:productId/checklist
/operation/:productId/quality
/operation/:productId/logistics
```

Note that I have several routes using expecting the same param `:productId` and different prefixes and suffixes to it. And all the layout pages wrapping all these routes/pages has a sidebar with links to different products.

So if I'm viewing page `/financial/100/taxes` and click on product with ID 333, the `Link` component should be aware of the rest of the URL to concatenate and provide the `href="/financial/333/taxes"` accordingly.

I'm wondering if there is a way for the `Link` component (or the component usingit) to know the raw active route so I can safely replace the `:productId` by the respective ID, keeping the constant parts of the URL. However, hooks like `useLocation` or `useMatch` only provided me with the actual parsed-params path (`/financial/123/taxes` instead of `/financial/:productId/taxes`) to do this.

Comment: There may be, but it might depend on your routing structure/organization. Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] of your routing/navigation code?

Comment: @DrewReese, I was currently getting `useLocation().pathname` and replacing the current ID by the newest. But I recently faced an issue in a route with a second param, `/operation/:productId/logistics/:orderId` where both params got the same value, therefore an undiscriminated string replacement updated both params.

I know `String.prototype.replace`has some advanced arguments that may help me replacing only the first param, but I wonder if React Router has some hook out-of-the-box to my use-case, or if community has some smarter solution.

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm asking to see what code you have currently, so we may make suggestions. Depending on route/code structure I can see very trivial solutions, or very convoluted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that replacement is just fine in my use-case, although it is not a killer solution, mainly for params that may match with other parts of the URL or may coincide with other params (e.g. `/:param1/:param2`, where `param1` and `param2` are both number, for example, and may assume a equal value at some point):

```
import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Link({ productId, productName }) {
  const params = useParams()
  const location = useLocation()
  const productURL = location.pathname.replace(
    `/${params.productId}/`, 
    `/${productId}/`
  )

  return (
    <Link to={productURL}>{productName}</Link>
  )
}
```

Another way to overcome this was by using `useMatch`, but it's way more limited and less generic:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { generatePath, Link, useLocation, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom'

function Link({ productId, productName }) {
  const location = useLocation()
  const financialMatcher = useMatch('/financial/:productId/*')
  const operationMatcher = useMatch('/operation/:productId/*')
  const productURL = useMemo(() => {
    const matcher = financialMatcher || operationMatcher
    const route = matcher ? matcher.pattern.path : location.pathname

    return generatePath(route, {
      ...matcher.params,
      productId,
    })
  }, [location.pathname, financialMatcher, operationMatcher])

  return (
    <Link to={productURL}>{productName}</Link>
  )
}
```

And, yeah, it seems the closest method to obtain the raw route in `react-router-dom` is by using the `useMatch` hook.